# Scanning card with card.io

Tags: android, camera, scanning, card.io

I have a project in which you want to scan the card. For this task I use the library [card.io](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK). Recently I updated library to the latest version (5.4.0) And now, instead of scanning the card are changed to enter it manually. What did I do wrong? All settings are made according to instructions.

**AndroidManifest**

```
    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="15"
            android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gallery3d.permission.GALLERY_PROVIDER" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <activity android:name="io.card.payment.CardIOActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
            <activity android:name="io.card.payment.DataEntryActivity" />
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false" />
```

Then, this class in which I try open scanActivity(CardIOActivity)

```
private static void launchCardIoPhoto(Context ctx) {
        if (!(ctx instanceof Activity)) return;
        //Intent scanIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        Intent scanIntent = new Intent(ctx, CardIOActivity.class);
        //scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_APP_TOKEN, CARD_IO_API_KEY);
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_EXPIRY, false);
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_POSTAL_CODE, false);
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CVV, false);
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_MANUAL_ENTRY, true);
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_USE_CARDIO_LOGO, true);
        BankokApplication.app().ignoreNextResume();

        Fragment fragment = ((Activity) ctx).getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.bottom_sheet_container);
        if (fragment != null && fragment instanceof CardScanReceiver){
            fragment.startActivityForResult(scanIntent, REQ_CODE_CARD_IO_PHOTO);
        }else {
            ((Activity) ctx).startActivityForResult(scanIntent, REQ_CODE_CARD_IO_PHOTO);
        }
    }
```

And when I try to do that, I have something like this:
[image]

**Update from the comments:**

Tested on

- Asus Z00AD (Zenphone)
- Huawei
- Nexus 5
- Genymotion

The example application from card.io works as expected

**EDIT**

 
Find error:

```
No implementation found for boolean io.card.payment.CardScanner.nUseX86() (tried Java_io_card_payment_CardScanner_nUseX86 and Java_io_card_payment_CardScanner_nUseX86__)
Failed to load native library: No implementation found for boolean io.card.payment.CardScanner.nUseX86() (tried Java_io_card_payment_CardScanner_nUseX86 and Java_io_card_payment_CardScanner_nUseX86__)
```

Comment: What device are you testing it on?

Comment: Asus Z00AD (Zenphone), Huawei, Nexus 5  and Genymotion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix problem.
The project was the native libraries of the previous version card.io after removal of library data it worked correctly.

Comment: what is library data? do you mean libs directory in Android project?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that? Exactly how did you fix the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that card.io cannot initialize the device camera and falls to the manual input.

If your device has a camera, **check that the camera is not in use**, and add this to your manifest (from [the documentation](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK)) to avoid requiring unnecesary funcitionalities of the camera:

```
<!-- Camera features - recommended -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />
```

Also, if your device runs Android 6 and the user has denied the camera permission, card.io will fall to manual card input.

Comment: it is in the project, I forgot to insert a poll

Comment: Is the camera in use? Have your tried restarting the device?

Comment: The camera is in order. Do not restart the device. Download the application from the library, it works fine

Comment: Are you using Android 6? have you denied the camera permission?

Comment: Permissions to the camera I get. Checking 6.5, 4.2.2 version of Android

Comment: I have class which extends Application, maybe I need to do something in it?